# how to make fancy scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

how to make fancy scroll? something like this image.

[alt text http://img237.imageshack.us/img237/5896/fancyscroll.gif](http://img237.imageshack.us/img237/5896/fancyscroll.gif)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for showing fancy scroll bar in body. You can get this in any of your control -

```
<HTML> 
<HEAD>

<STYLE TYPE="text/css">

HTML, BODY{ 
scrollbar-face-color:#00BDE6; 
scrollbar-arrow-color:#000000; 
scrollbar-track-color:#000000; 
scrollbar-shadow-color:#000000; 
scrollbar-highlight-color:#000000; 
scrollbar-3dlight-color:#000000; 
scrollbar-darkshadow-color:#000000; 
}


</STYLE>

<TITLE></TITLE> 
</HEAD>
```

Comment: IS there any fix for FF and Chrome

Comment: @Bharanikumar - Not sure how to handle this for other browsers, but there are quite a lot of tools for getting fancy scrollbars. Guess you need to try them probably. Check this link might help -

http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/css/javascript-css-scrollbars/